# less css and node js troubles

Tags: node.js, less

When I try to install less css compiler under my Ubuntu 13.10 box I get following message and lescss don't working. In what way I can fix the problem? I execute:

```
sudo npm install -g less
```

After this I get e list with OK messages:

```
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/cryptiles
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/ctype/0.5.2
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/combined-stream
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/sntp
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/boom
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/0.0.5
```

And list finished with following:

```
 /usr/local/bin/lessc -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc
    less@1.7.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/less
    ├── mime@1.2.11
    ├── mkdirp@0.3.5
    ├── source-map@0.1.33 (amdefine@0.1.0)
    ├── clean-css@2.1.8 (commander@2.1.0)
    └── request@2.34.0 (json-stringify-safe@5.0.0, forever-agent@0.5.2, aws-sign2@0.5.0, qs@0.6.6, tunnel-agent@0.3.0, oauth-sign@0.3.0, node-uuid@1.4.1, tough-cookie@0.12.1, http-signature@0.10.0, hawk@1.0.0, form-data@0.1.2)
```

After this when I tried the following commands:

```
echo "@foo: 25px; #foobar{font-size: @foo};" > style.less
sudo lessc ./style.less ./style.css
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/env: node: No such file or directory
```

After I executed

```
ln -s /usr/bin/node /usr/local/bin/nodejs
```

and created symlinks there is no errors but lessc compiler don't working properly.
I have created file to test. It content is:

cat style.less

```
@color: #4D926F;

#header {
  color: @color;
}
h2 {
  color: @color;
}`
```

and after trying

```
lessc styles.less > styles.css
```

There is created file - styles.css but the file is empty. 
I also try commands that I tryed before - see top on the post.

```
lessc styles.less styles.css
```

But it not working. There is no file as a result. 
When I tried

```
sudo npm install -g less
```

In the last line I receive following error.

```
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/delayed-stream/-/delayed-stream-0.0.5.tgz
/usr/bin/lessc -> /usr/lib/node_modules/less/bin/lessc
npm ERR! Refusing to delete: /usr/bin/lessc not in /usr/lib/node_modules/less
File exists: /usr/bin/lessc
Move it away, and try again. 

npm ERR! System Linux 3.11.0-19-generic
npm ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "less"
npm ERR! cwd /home/georgi
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.3
npm ERR! path /usr/bin/lessc
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/georgi/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: Those exact commands worked for me pasted into my node server. Running ubuntu 12.04 with node installed. Can you run node from where you are (is it in your PATH)?

Comment: The question is edited.

Comment: When you type `env node --version` does it tell you your node version or does it tell you *"No such file or directory"*? And, what is the output of `which env`? What distro of Linux are you using?

Comment: where is your lessc version ? `lessc -v`

Comment: lessc -v don't output nothing.

Comment: normally, lessc print this on your console : `lessc 1.4.1 (LESS Compiler) [JavaScript]` and if you try just `lessc` to get the 'man page'

Comment: So I have general issue with installation ..  What I can do?

Comment: try `sudo npm cache clean` and `npm cache clean` and restart less install

Comment: try sudo npm cache clean and npm cache clean - this don't change nothing. Never mind I'm using koala now:  http://koala-app.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `>` command operator is incorrect in your command. The correct command is :

```
lessc [sourcefile] [destfile]
```

For your example, your command is :

```
lessc styles.less styles.css
```

Comment: I alto tried lessc styles.less styles.css but there is no file as result.

Comment: Try `lessc styles.less styles.css --verbose`

Comment: lessc styles.less styles.css --verbose dont generate error but don't output nothing.